# Feynman slash identity

Tags: notation, dirac-matrices

How would one simplify the expression
$\gamma^0 {\not}p \;\gamma^0$
?

My guess would be that its

$$\begin{align}
\gamma^0 {\not}p \;\gamma^0&=\gamma^0 \gamma^{\mu} p_{\mu} \;\gamma^0\\
&=\gamma^0\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^0 p_{\mu}\\
&=\gamma^{\mu\dagger}p_{\mu}\\
&={\not}p^{\dagger}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

You are right until the last step. Expanding the adjoint of the gamma matrices we have:
$$(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger = (\gamma^{0^\dagger}, \gamma^{k^\dagger}) = (\gamma^0, -\gamma^k).$$

So, assuming the metric to be $\eta_{\mu \nu} = \operatorname{diag}(+,\,-,\,-,\,-)$ we get:

$$(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger p_\mu = \eta_{\mu \nu}(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger p^\nu = (p_0\gamma^0, +p_k\gamma^k) = \not{p}.$$

Note the double minus sign from the spatial components of the metric and the adjoint of the gamma matrices.

T.

Comment: What "double minus sign" are you referring to? You are wrong and the original post is right.

Comment: The minus sign from the spatial components of the metric and the other minus from the spatial components of the adjoint gamma. The original post is wrong because it is not using the first property I wrote. At the end of the day, I have just expanded the operations on each component, there is nothing wrong in that procedure. If you recognise an error on it just enlight us

Comment: It's basic math. $\eta_{\mu \nu} p^\nu = p_\mu =  (p_0, +p_k)$, there is no extra minus sign.

Comment: The adjointed gamma is also contracted with the metric